# How to debug nodejs chaincode on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I can't read my logs on the chaincode in nodejs on Hyperledger Fabric 1.4
I'm trying to read the logs by :

```
`docker logs -f <<chaincode_container_instance>>`
```

but the only log I can see is this:

```
`async instantiate(ctx) {
         console.log('Instantiate the contract');
    }`
```

here it is:

```
` > fabric-chaincode-node start "--peer.address" "peer0.org1.example.com:7052"
(node:16) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
Command succeeded
Instantiate the contract`
```

but not the log on my transaction:

```
`async createDocument(ctx, documentId, name, hash, owner, sector, timeStamp) {
     console.log("id: "+ documentId+"timeStamp: "+ timeStamp);
             ...
         <<REST OF THE CODE>>`
```

And the transaction execution it's ok, because I can see on the couchdb a new register.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
On developing process I stoped the basic network and starited it again. 
Then I installed again the chaincode but the docker images were the previous ones, so I didn't update the changes. 
Deleting the images of the contract instances updates the changes and shows the traces.